# How to set width of responsive carousel?

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel

I am developing a website with carousel slider but carousal slider goes to the outside external div. It is because of carousel Slider takes dynamic width with related to screen resolution. Should anybody help me to fix it.
What i done is here :
   http://code-dynamix.com/blazemedia/fdfs.html

The problem in the above link is in division above the footer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post code here....reference links are not welcome!!

Comment: Its not the reference link its the link of my website where i get stuck.

Comment: *that* is called reference link only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the 
**overflow: hidden;**
in your div class (.upcoming) this would hide anything outside the box

Comment: In which div should i add it?

Comment: I am glad you solve the issue. Please mark the question as answered

Comment: @KhaledMohamedP : what you have suggested is **hiding the mess**...SO is about **cleaning and solving the mess**....!!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
.upcoming{
overflow: hidden; /* inside overflow:hidden; in main div */
}
.caroufredsel_wrapper{
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 126px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add width 100% for caroufredsel_wrapper class, overflow: hidden for .upcoming div. That is

```
.caroufredsel_wrapper {
    width : 100% !important;
```

}

```
.upcoming {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

in css file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- Try setting the width to 100%.

> ```
> <div id="wrapper">
>   <div id="carousel">
>       <div><img src="img" /></div>
>       <div><img src="img" /></div>
>       <div><img src="img" /></div>
>       <div><img src="img" /></div>
>   </div>
>   <div id="title">
>       <h3>Header</h3>
>       <p><a href="#">Link Name</a></p>
>   </div>
>   <div id="pager"></div>
> </div>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem is this**: you have given inline-css to the divs...

`width:510px; height:396px; background:url(images/Layer61new.png); position:absolute;`

so no water whatever you give in the css, `inline-css` would always over-write the `width` and `height` coming from the css

**How to recover?** Remove all the inline css if you want a responsive stuff and play with `width` and `height` through your css....because on resizing....your stuffs are getting hidden withouth resizing....*this is not responsive thing, its just hiding the mess* :)